# Prove $f(\overline{U})) \subset \overline{f(U)}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm facing this problem: For $f : (X,\mathcal{T}) \to (Y,\mathcal{T}')$ a continuous map between topological space, then for any subset $U \subset X$ is $f(\overline{U}) \subset \overline{f(U)}$.

I know the usual proof, but I´d like is this one is right:

Let be $x \in f(\overline{U})$. So for any open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ is $V \cap f(U) \neq \emptyset$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $f^{-1}(x)$.

Using $f^{-1}(x) \in \overline{U}$ is $f^{-1}(V) \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

So $f(f^{-1}(V) \cap U) = V \cap f(U) \neq \emptyset$, then $x \in \overline{f(U)}$.

Is this right? I'm not sure.

And here another try:

Suppose exist $x \in f(\overline{U})$ with $x \notin \overline{f(U)}.$ Then exist an open neightborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V \cap f(U) = \emptyset$.

For $z \in \overline{U}$ such that $f(z) = x$, for any $W$ open neighborhood of $z$ is $W \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Then exist $h \in W \cap A$ and $f(h) \in f(W) \cap f(A)$. So for the adequate $f(W) \subset V$ is $f(W) \cap U \neq \emptyset$ but $V \cap f(U) = \emptyset$. A contradiction.

Is this last one right?

Thanks!

Comment: Be careful about which space your neighborhoods are in. You write "let $x\in f(\overline U)$. So for any open neigborhood $V$ of $x$ is $V\cap f(U)\neq \varnothing$". This is not right. What you really have is that $x = f(x')$ for some $x\in X$ such that for every open neigborhood $V\ni x$, $V\cap U\neq\varnothing$. EDIT: Sorry, when you said "so [etc]", I thought you claimed that [etc] was a consequence.

Comment: In general is true $f(U \cap V) = f(U) \cap f(V)$?

Comment: If $f$ is not injective, $U \cap V$ could be empty even if $f(U) \cap f(V)$ is not.

Comment: And the converse? $f(U) \cap f(V)$ not empty but $U \cap V$ yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be continuous and suppose $y \in f[\overline{U}]$. So $y=f(x)$ with $x \in \overline{U}$. Now let $O$ be an open neighbourhood of $y$, then $f^{-1}[O]$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ (here we use that $f$ is continuous), so $f^{-1}[O] \cap U$ is non-empty (as $x \in \overline{U}$), say that $x' \in f^{-1}[O] \cap U$. But then $f(x') \in f[U]$ and $f(x') \in O$ so that $O$ intersects $f[U]$. As $O$ was an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $y$, $y \in \overline{f[U]}$ and the inclusion has been shown.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to use points at all. Since $\overline{f(U)}$ is closed the continuity of $f$ implies $f^{-1}(\overline{f(U)})$ is closed too. But $$U \subset f^{-1}(f(U)) \subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(U)}) \implies \overline U \subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(U)})$$ because the latter set is closed. Thus
$$ f(\overline U) \subset f(f^{-1}(\overline{f(U)})) = \overline{f(U)}.$$

Comment: I know this proof, I´m interesting in the previous using elements and neighborhoods. Thanks.

Comment: Please, answer my question using elements. I knew that proof.